# Clojure / Jetty: Force URL to only be Hit Once at a Time

Tags: clojure, locking, jetty

I am working on a Clojure / Jetty web service.  I have a special url that I want to only be serviced one request at a time.  If the url was requested, and before it returns, the url is requested again, I want to immediately return.  So in more core.clj, where I defined my routes, I have something like this:

```
(def work-in-progress (ref false))
```

Then sometime later

```
(compojure.core/GET "/myapp/internal/do-work" []
    (if @work-in-progress
        "Work in Progress please try again later"
        (do
            (dosync
                (ref-set work-in-progress true))
            (do-the-work)
            (dosync
                (ref-set rebuild-in-progress false))
            "Job completed Successfully")))
```

I have tried this on local Jetty server but I seem to be able to hit the url twice and double the work.  What is a good pattern / way to implement this in Clojure in a threaded web server environment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Imagine a following [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition#Software) for the solution proposed in the question.

1. Thread A starts to execute handler's body. `@work-in-progress` is `false`, so it enters the `do` expression. However, before it managed to set the value of `work-in-progress` to `true`...
2. Thread B starts to execute handler's body. `@work-in-progress` is false, so it enters the `do` expression.

Now two threads are executing `(do-the-work)` concurrently. That's not what we want.

To prevent this problem check and set the value of the ref in a `dosync` transaction.

```
(compojure.core/GET "/myapp/internal/do-work" []
  (if (dosync
        (when-not @work-in-progress
          (ref-set work-in-progress true)))
    (try
      (do-the-work)
      "Job completed Successfully"
      (finally
        (dosync
          (ref-set work-in-progress false))))
    "Work in Progress please try again later"))
```

Another abstraction which you might find useful in this scenario is an atom and [`compare-and-set!`](http://www.clodoc.org/doc/clojure.core/compare-and-set!).

```
(def work-in-progress (atom false))

(compojure.core/GET "/myapp/internal/do-work" []
  (if (compare-and-set! work-in-progress false true)
    (try
      (do-the-work)
      "Job completed Successfully"
      (finally
        (reset! work-in-progress false)))
    "Work in Progress please try again later"))
```

Comment: This is really neat: I'd never considered using `compare-and-set!` to transactionally get information about an atom while changing it to something else.

Comment: You'll probably want to make sure you release the "lock" in the event `(do-the-work)` throws an exception, or at any rate notice the problem and do something about it. So, I'd replace `(do (do-the-work) (release))` with `(try (do-the-work) (finally (release)))` or similar (see my answer for a full snippet with actual locks).

Answer (score 2):

Actually this is the natural use case for a lock; in particular, a [`java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html).

The same pattern came up in my answer to an earlier SO question, [Canonical Way to Ensure Only One Instance of a Service Is Running / Starting / Stopping in Clojure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16131420/canonical-way-to-ensure-only-one-instance-of-a-service-is-running-starting-s); I'll repeat the relevant piece of code here:

```
(import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock)

(def lock (ReentrantLock.))

(defn start []
  (if (.tryLock lock)
    (try
      (do-stuff)
      (finally (.unlock lock)))
    (do-other-stuff)))
```

The `tryLock` method attempts to acquire the lock, returning `true` if it succeeds in doing so and `false` otherwise, not blocking in either case.

Answer (score 1):

Consider queueing the access to the resource as well - in addition to getting an equivalent functionality to that of locks/flags, queues let you observe the resource contention, among other advantages.